# Installation of latest MySql server

Tags: installation, mysql

I have downloaded the MySql 5.6.11 win32 version. Facing problem in installing this downloaded version. I can't find any setup file.

I am new to this please help me to install MySql server on my Windows 7 machine.

Download link: [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/). I have downloaded a zip archive.

Comment: and the install instructions dont help? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-install-archive.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a huge installer banner on that page, you want the installer from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/5.6.html - the first one is a full, offline installer, the second one is an online version (downloads everything during the setup).

By the way, are you sure you don't want just to install XAMPP, which comes with Apache, PHP, MySQL, FileZilla FTP Server, Mercury and TomCat? If you want to develop stuff with PHP, it might be a better choice, as it's preconfigured. And you can start MySQL alone from that package as well. There's the link: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html